# How to pick generics from function in union type dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, narrowing

Lets say I have a function like this:

```
type FooParams <Params extends unknown[], Result> = { 
 name: string, 
 request: (...params: Params) => Promise<Result> 
}

const foo = <Params extends unknown[], Result>(params: FooParams<Params, Result>) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Lets also say I have a couple of requests and a "store" containing those requests:

```
interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const getTodos: () => Promise<Todo[]> = () => Promise.resolve([{ id: 2, title: 'clean' }]);

const getTodo: (id: number) => Promise<Todo> = (id: number) => Promise.resolve({ id, title: 'clean' });

const requestStore = {
  getTodo: {
    name: 'getTodo',
    request: getTodo,
  },
  getTodos: {
    name: 'getTodos',
    request: getTodos,
  },
} as const;
```

I would now like to generate foo-functions for each request in the store.

Adding them manually with explicit key for each request in the store works:

```
// Works
foo(requestStore['getTodo'])
```

But adding them dynamically like this does not work:

```
// Does not work. Error message:
// Type '(() => Promise<Todo[]>) | ((id: number) => Promise<Todo>)' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<Todo[]>'.
//  Type '(id: number) => Promise<Todo>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<Todo[]>'.(2322)
const createFooFromStore = (requestName: keyof typeof requestStore) => () => {
  const { name, request } = requestStore[requestName]
  foo({ name, request })
}
```

Is there someway one could re-write this so that a foo-function could be created for each entry in the "requestStore"?

Here is a playground link with the example code:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-OZgKF7O+zQJ-mbFKTWG0emUmxOUF1t8nUGngrZi5pv0xNjHPSgE8gj43ayMgKu4voEB5HjgzCnoOF5Xjed6gH+T4gQuYFvpwYgflYyIAMzIsibhkgk0TGMg5DwHAMDvCW+r-EWwAAHJWlADAQCAcCJPekAceqpjOsANEQCys5tB0KYUnIyhBrw9GEqk9GCew9FMUGnAdPmEqBhAMl8RYSoREAA)

In which the "request"-parameter at the very bottom shows an error message.

Comment: Does this question really depend on react-query? If you could refactor into a [mre] that doesn't depend on any third-party library, you might get more engagement.  If you do make such an edit and want me to take a look, please leave a comment mentioning @jcalz so I'm notified.  Good luck!

Comment: You are right, it does not depend on react-query and can be simplified. I updated the question and would be grateful for any help @jcalz!

Comment: you haven't shown how `foo` is defined / typed. Please put this in a typescript playground!

Comment: Added a playground link @TkDodo - there is a definition of the foo-function at the top (with just a comment in the body but the parameter types are causing the problem, I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant post this playground link into the comments section... but this works [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVGBTAHlbMAEwhgCVsBHAV22gGUoQAnbAbQGtsBPEOcqrQZNWAXQB8ACgAOAQ2ayAthABcMDAEoU4mAG8AUDBgB6YzFZRqzMDDkLlMJjGAALbMA6Pu07DACWYHDYzAEA5obm2JbWtvJKEPoAvvr6AQTMcLLAvhggREgGRn5EamDUigBGwQDcEVB+UAA22GrQIWChtcn6oJCwoVG5+aowklrIOgAKzCCKfhDYmHkgbBIoo+NTM3MLAHSsECCNAG7Ykmy6-iUwAEwANI4NzWoA5MDNsmAvMImiGrU9cDQGADKBDEBqSTFUrlKrMTYwaazeaLcE6VBQ65lSrBBFInbYfZ0I6nSSXYoPepNFowN4fL4-f4pXrA1g0OhQRgsXyoQogwbLNR8oxgJQ0l6g8EvO4RIxsoRQNSS5YyoyJVX8sHLEbCmCixTi5XDaWyyLs6BKgXDDXqpIwWSkFlQWpQby+CjmzkiHleHx8M0KrmsFKmGAAdRYHASCBAknlHKD7AlVpALz++hjccECe9bGTWuN6eZQNgwFYsgIADFEJXton1pgcPhCCQYFxePxXX7+PHhNypL2oAA5MVqTTaDYTzODxNsQcjg1Fp329Zl7AV7DVkC12aJyQAIiNIH3WlDx1kjWKgL6MAqq-LVZrde9B6PEBPJjM58vRGvwOA97ro+27Ptyr4Cu+p5mAE35Xn+pYPpuT67t6NwNlgeAEMQpDtv6XbYP6M7egO2bQAuNLjhMk5UZc06kV63JzvR5F-D8+hAA)

```
// The type constraint here does the trick.
// It allows every specified key in the Requeststore as an input for foo
// The 
const foo = <T extends RequestStore[keyof RequestStore]>(params: T) => {
  // return params to check type infering
  return params
}

interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const getTodos: () => Promise<Todo[]> = () => Promise.resolve([{ id: 2, title: 'clean' }]);

const getTodo: (id: number) => Promise<Todo> = (id: number) => Promise.resolve({ id, title: 'clean' });

// if you want to ensure typesafety here you can use the new satisfies keyword to prevent wrong request definitions but you don't need it

const requestStore = {
  getTodo: {
    name: 'getTodo',
    request: getTodo,
  },
  getTodos: {
    name: 'getTodos',
    request: getTodos,
  },
} as const satisfies Record<string, { name: string, request: (...args: any[]) => any }>;
type RequestStore = typeof requestStore

// Works
foo(requestStore['getTodo'])
foo(requestStore['getTodos'])


const createFooFromStore = <T extends keyof typeof requestStore>(requestName: T) => () => foo(requestStore[requestName])

const a = createFooFromStore("getTodo") // valid
const b = createFooFromStore("getTodos") // valid
const c = createFooFromStore("getTos") // invalid

const createFooFromStore2 = <T extends keyof typeof requestStore>(requestName: T) => () => { foo(requestStore[requestName]) }
```